# ESLint React PropTypes, 'prop' is missing in prop validation

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a stateless react component

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default props => <StyledButton>{props.children}</StyledButton>

StyledButton.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
}
StyledButton.defaultProps = {
    children: null,
}
```

And a class component

```
class Thumbnail extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           color: 'red',
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <button>{this.props.children}</button>
       )
    }
}

Thumbnail.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
}
Thumbnail.defaultProps = {
    children: null,
}
```

My eslintrc file

```
module.exports = {
"extends": "airbnb",
"plugins": [
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y",
    "import"
],
"rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "semi": 0,
    "indent": ["error", 4],
    "react/jsx-indent": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt": 0
}
};
```

Eslint complains that 'children is missing in prop validation' in the stateless component.
But it's fine in the class component.

Spent 2 hours trying to fix this, Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are exporting the stateless component directly without any variable holding it meanwhile you are creating `propTypes` and `defaultProps` for `StyledButton` which doesn't exist. Try this.

```
const StyledButton = props => <button>{props.children}</button>;

StyledButton.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
};

StyledButton.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
};

export default StyledButton;
```

Comment: @kevinjanada I also recommend not to use null in the default props instead use and empty span.